# case comments by default published community

Tags: customer-portal, case-comment

when a portal user is adding comments isPublished is by default setting to true.Why is this happening any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation for [`isPublished`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm) fields says:

> Indicates whether the CaseComment is visible to customers in the Self-Service portal (true) or not (false).

It is a desired behavior as the flag would be on for community user.

For internal users it is optional because; internal users working on case would not want community users to know about certain discussions via case comments.

Comment: thanks for the update.I saw the documentation but it does not say that when a portal user enters the case comments,it will be published even if i did not check the published checkbox.Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: looks like when a comment is posted from portal is defaults to public, you have to write a update on trigger.